# Divide a column in several colums in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-core

I'm trying to divide the information of a column in several columns because a just need the information of a table to print it, but I don't want to have blanks space, so the more information I have in the page, the less sheets I use.

This is what I want to do:
[image]

Comment: Will there always be 8 values? Why do you want to do with ASP and not in the SQL?

Comment: Its just an example, and i want it in ASP because this information will be printed its like a report that I'm doing, I just need the information of a single column so that to save space I want to do what is seen in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function on Javascript

```js
$(function($) {
  var num_cols = 4,
    container = $('.split-list'),
    listItem = 'tr',
    listClass = 'sub-list';
  container.each(function() {
    var items_per_col = new Array(),
      items = $(this).find(listItem),
      min_items_per_col = Math.floor(items.length / num_cols),
      difference = items.length - (min_items_per_col * num_cols);
    for (var i = 0; i < num_cols; i++) {
      if (i < difference) {
        items_per_col[i] = min_items_per_col + 1;
      } else {
        items_per_col[i] = min_items_per_col;
      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < num_cols; i++) {
      $(this).append($('<div class="col-3"></div>').addClass(listClass));
      for (var j = 0; j < items_per_col[i]; j++) {
        var pointer = 0;
        for (var k = 0; k < i; k++) {
          pointer += items_per_col[k];
        }
        $(this).find('.' + listClass).last().append(items[j + pointer]);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

In the variable called `num_cols` you can set the numbers of columns do you want to have.
And to make this function work, you just have to create a `div` container that contains the table with the class `split-list`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try handling this with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) - 1 AS rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn / 4 = 0 THEN Name END) AS Name1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn / 4 = 1 THEN Name END) AS Name2
    -- add more CASE expressions for more columns/data
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    rn % 4
ORDER BY
    rn % 4;
```

### Demo

Comment: Why 4? I don't get that.

Comment: @KeithL I don't get it either, and didn't get it right until I played around with the demo for about 10 minutes.  The basic idea here is the OP wants 4 rows max, with more data taking up more columns.  So, any time the modulus of the row number is 0 the data point goes in the first row, etc.  The column, on the other hand, is given by how many units of 4 have already been seen.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't expecting Tim to repost and I worked on it. This solution is for 2 columns and as many rows as needed.

NOTE: integer math returns whole numbers and also note that % is the mod function in math

```
select *
into #temp
from (values('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e'),('f'),('g'),('h')) a(name)

;with cte as 
(
    select rn = row_number() over (order by name)-1
        ,name
    from #temp
)

select rn / 2
    ,max(case when rn % 2 = 0 then name  end) Name1
    ,max(case when rn % 2 = 1 then name  end) Name2
from cte
group by rn / 2
```